# Error controlando el mensaje de error

Tags: spring

Estoy creando un error en el controlador con Spring y resulta que cuando devuelvo la petición con Postman me da un error de "N".

```
Unexpected 'N'
```

El código que tengo a continuación :

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{firstName}", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> showMessage(@PathVariable("firstName") String firstName)  {
        Customer persona = customerService.findCustomerByName(firstName);
        if (persona == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity("Not find a customer",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(persona, HttpStatus.OK);
    }   
}
```

Porque me devuelve esta excepción ?

Comment: eso es android studio? hasta ese nivel no he llegado

Comment: no , es con  eclipse